# Ajax success don't execute with node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax

success don't response, I have used this code:

> Client code:

```
function add(){
    var values = formserial(addd);
    var tok = "abc",
    var url= 'http://localhost:8181/add';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            dataType: "json",
            data:{ss:values,tok:tok},
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);        
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
            }
        });
}
```

> Server code:

```
    router.route('/add')
    .post(function(req, res) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

      res.json("New added!");
      console.log(""New added!");
    });
```

The console show "New added" but the success don't alert response.
Any solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the *http success status* (200):

```
var response = {
    status  : 200,
    success : 'New added!'
}

res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Otherwise the client doesn't know the response status.

Code `200` stands for **OK**: The request has succeeded.

For all status codes see [this](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

I hope it helps you, bye.

**UPDATED:** Alternative with [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post( url, { "ss":"values", "tok":"tok" }, function( data ) {
  alert(response);
}, "json");
```

Comment: Try to remove `res.json("New added!");` and replace that line with my code above, it should works.

Comment: And it doesn't work, isn'it? Ok, are you using chrome? Open the "Developer tools" (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and go to tab "Network", clear all the results (ban symbol icon) and try again, so you could see the response and its status.

Comment: OK,it works with google chrome,but it doesn't in firefox.Also the page make auto refresh and I don't undrestand why ?

Comment: nop,it show Object {status: 200, success: "New added!"}

Comment: I added window.location.href = 'index.html'; in success function but it don't redirect

Comment: Could you try with `$.post()` (check my updated answer) and format the json with double quotes?

Comment: No doesn't work with $.post(), I use jquery.min.js version(3.2.1)

Comment: And which Firefox version?

Comment: 53.0.3 Mozilla Firefox for ubuntu

Comment: Could you try with .done()? Append to your ajax call: `$.ajax(...).done(function() { alert("done!"); })`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem causing this in my case, was missing `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` in response header.